# deleted files doesn't free up space on nfs volume

Tags: centos7, filesystems, nfs, disk-space-utilization

I would like to hear your suggestion on why space is not released after files deletion.
Jira application uses nfs volume as shared jira home. 12 gb indexes snapshot is created per hour (oldest one is deleted and newest one is created) and the storage usage only increases.
I have checked process that holds deleted files (`lsof +L1`), open processes, nothing is found related to the issue. `du -sh` result is the same all the time, `df -h` increases, the difference is 700 GB. No .snapshot files are created.

Comment: What serves the NFS mount?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, a few services user the nfs but there correlation between creating index snapshot and increase of the usage

Comment: The question was, what is the system providing the NFS mount.